# Add windows "select folder" popup to Power Shell script

Tags: windows, powershell

The code below works perfectly except that each time you want to run it you have to edit the code to add the folder and path in from of $folder = "path"

```
$folder = "C:\0000"
$exec = "C:\Temp\Snap2HTML\Snap2HTML.exe"
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Process -FilePath $exec -ArgumentList "-path:`"$($_.FullName)`" -    outfile:`"$($_.FullName)`\$($_.Name)`.html`" -title:`"$($_.Name)`""
```

}

I am trying to add a windows select folder "pop-up" to the code below that would pass the selected folder to `$folder =` but my understanding of PS scripting is low.

I have tried the below but it does not work

```
Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory) {
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
    $FolderBrowserDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $FolderBrowserDialog.RootFolder = 'MyComputer'
    if ($initialDirectory) { $FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory }
    [void] $FolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog()
    return $FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath


$folder = .SelectedPath
$exec = "C:\Temp\Snap2HTML\Snap2HTML.exe"
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Process -FilePath $exec -ArgumentList "-path:`"$($_.FullName)`" -    outfile:`"$($_.FullName)`\$($_.Name)`.html`" -title:`"$($_.Name)`""
}
```

I have been continuing to try different things and I have found the new code below that opens the windows folder dialog box which works (on my machine) on another website.

This code stores the folder location in PowerShell as <$browse.SelectedPath>

I have not provided a link to the site as I am unsure if I am supposed to.

```
function Find-Folders {
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
    $browse = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $browse.SelectedPath = "C:\"
    $browse.ShowNewFolderButton = $false
    $browse.Description = "Select a directory"

    $loop = $true
    while($loop)
    {
        if ($browse.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
        {
        $loop = $false
        
        #Insert your script here
        
        } else
        {
            $res = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You clicked Cancel. Would you like to try again or exit?", "Select a location", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::RetryCancel)
            if($res -eq "Cancel")
            {
                #Ends script
                return
            }
        }
    }
    $browse.SelectedPath
    $browse.Dispose()
} Find-Folders
```

My code already uses <.SelectedPath> to tell my code which Folder to exicute in...

```
$folder = .SelectedPath
$exec = "C:\Temp\Snap2HTML\Snap2HTML.exe"
Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Process -FilePath $exec -ArgumentList "-path:`"$($_.FullName)`" -outfile:`"$($_.FullName)`\$($_.Name)`.html`" -title:`"$($_.Name)`""
}
```

However when I combine the code and run it in powershell I get the following error in red text

```
.SelectedPath : The term '.SelectedPath' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable
program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:33 char:11
+ $folder = .SelectedPath
+           ~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.SelectedPath:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: just do `$folder = Get-Folder`

Comment: Sadly this does nothing.

Answer (score 3):

Of course it doesn't work you got a few basics wrong :)

```
Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory) {
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
    $FolderBrowserDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $FolderBrowserDialog.RootFolder = 'MyComputer'

    # if $initialDirectory is set and it's not $Null or empty
    # then make it the Initial Directory
    # If $InitialDirectory is not set, it will use the current wordking directory by default.
    if (-not [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($initialDirectory)) {
        # # you should evaluate using some logic to test the value of $InitialDirectory, before assigning it
        # # Search for Test-Path and Resolve-Path
        # Assigns the values $InitialDirectory
        $FolderBrowserDialog.InitialDirectory = $initialDirectory
    }
    
    # open window to select a Directory, starting with the value of .InitalDirectory
    [void]$FolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog()     
    
    # returns the value of the selected Path
    return $FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath

######
# Close the function!!!
# It was likely a big part of your issues.
######
}


# call the function and load the returned value in $Folder
# you do not need to use .SelectedPath here because it was already specified in the function
# You can optionally pass any path to Get-Folder, like
# # # Get-Folder 'C:'
# or
# # # Get-Folder("D:\is\my\directory")
# so the select window starts from that directory
$folder = Get-Folder 

# $Folder now has the path of the directory you chose as a string value.
$folder
```

Comment: Thank you but sadly it does not work. When C+V into power shell and the return button hit nothing happens.

Comment: the folder selection window might be hidden in background, or take a little bit to appear the first time around

Comment: Just tested on both 5.1 and 7.4.1 and it works. I also edited the solution with a  `[void]` to `$FolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog()` otherwise `$folder` ends up with a extra value

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for all suggestions, it is appreciated.

After trying various ways I have managed to get this to work for me and I am posting this here in case it may help some one else.

I decided to use this Power Shell code to select folder code together with the additional code to run Snap2HTML as this code has the added benefit of a retry or cancel popup.

```
function Run-Snap2HTML {
    [Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
    [System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
    $browse = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $browse.SelectedPath = "C:\"
    $browse.ShowNewFolderButton = $false
    $browse.Description = "Select a directory"

    $loop = $true
    while($loop)
    {
        if ($browse.ShowDialog() -eq "OK")
        {
        $loop = $false

            $folder = $browse.SelectedPath
            $exec = "C:\Temp\Snap2HTML\Snap2HTML.exe"
            Get-ChildItem -Path $folder -Directory | ForEach-Object {
                Start-Process -FilePath $exec -ArgumentList "-path:`"$($_.FullName)`" -outfile:`"$($_.FullName)`\$($_.Name)`.html`" -title:`"$($_.Name)`""
            }
        
        } else
        {
            $res = [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox]::Show("You clicked Cancel. Would you like to try again or exit?", "Select a location", [System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons]::RetryCancel)
            if($res -eq "Cancel")
            {
                #Ends script
                return
            }
        }
    }
    $browse.SelectedPath
    $browse.Dispose()
} Run-Snap2HTML
```

Answer (score -1):

Try following :

```
Function Get-Folder($initialDirectory) {
    [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('System.Windows.Forms')
    $FolderBrowserDialog = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog
    $FolderBrowserDialog.RootFolder = 'MyComputer'
    if ($initialDirectory) { $FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath = $initialDirectory }
    [void] $FolderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog()
    return $FolderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath


$folder = .SelectedPath
$exec = "C:\Temp\Snap2HTML\Snap2HTML.exe"

Get-ChildItem -Path $folder | ForEach-Object {
    Start-Process -FilePath $_ $exec -ArgumentList "-path $_.FullName -outfile $_.FullName$_.Name.html -title $_.Name" }

}


Get-Folder -$initialDirectory pwd
```

Comment: Sadly nothing happens

Comment: Code was tested and works.

Comment: No that is wrong. While the choose folder popup box does open and I can select a folder of my choice, the rest of the code from <$folder = .SelectedPath> down does not when it worked perfectly before. So some how the new code has broken the over task.